# Как сделать остановку цикла из в него вложенного?

Tags: java, циклы

Допустим есть цикл (1) в цикле (2). Как мне остановить цикл 2 из цикла 1? Как мне использовать оператор `continue` чтобы продолжить итерацию цикла 2?

```
while(...){
    ...
    for(...){
        ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если можно добавить имя блоку, то так:

```
loop1: {
    while(...){
        ...
        for(...){
            ???
            //break; // break for (...) and continue while()
            //continue loop1; // break for (...) and continue while()
            //break loop1; // break while (...) and exit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и это соответствует постановке вопроса: "Как мне использовать оператор continue..."

Answer (score 3):

Есть вариант работы с метками, но он не очень читаем, и вообще в продакшене я его ни разу не видел. Можно просто логической переменной:

```
boolean active = true;
while(...) {
    for (...) {
        if (...) {
            active = false;
            break;
        }
    ...
    }
    if (!active) break;
}
```

Comment: а еще можно так `boolean b = true; while(... && b)`, при условии что цикл 1 последний